# vuetify: label inside v-img isn't shown

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In a v-dialog I use a v-img element with a label inside and that label isn't shown. I recreated the problem inside [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/unkrass/pen/gOarERY). When you open the dialog there should be a label reading "Mountains" on top of the image. The actual problem is this style that is automatically added by Vuetify:

```
.v-application--is-ltr .v-responsive__sizer~.v-responsive__content {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
```

I tried to override the style, but it doesn't work because the style and the reponsive elements are probably dynamically rendered after CSS is compiled.

The problem also occurs when the image is not inside a v-dialog.

In [this example from the Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/#fixed-ratio) it works and I would rather not hack it with a load of CSS.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can't take the v-row containing the label outside the v-img?

Comment: That does not work and also in this vuetify example it was implemented with a row inside the v-img, so it has to work somehow
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/#fixed-ratio

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I removed an obsolete `display: block;` on my image's style which broke it.